# How do the horns of my race work?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races

In a medieval fantasy world with low magic, humans and a race of horned humanoids (unnamed) exist. The world is similar to Earth with low magic and some creatures that don't exist, like griffins.

> Definition of low magic: Magic works; intelligent creatures can use
>   it until they become exhausted and have to wait until their body absorbs more magic in air
>   passively. Magic is hard to use in combat because its use requires a lot of
>   concentration and it isn't particularly powerful. For example, a
>   mage can throw fire for a few seconds at only 1 enemy. Out of combat,
>   magic is used for everyday tasks. Mages are not as important as they
>   seem, they are not noble and will not become one by using magic.

The horned humanoids are very similar to humans in intelligence and appearance, excepting that they have horns, vivid colorful eyes and vertical pupils (like cats or some reptiles).

They have more strength and resilience in all respects. Usually, 1 horned humanoid is equal to 3 humans physically.

The horns are very socially important for them. It is more shameful to break a horn than lose an arm or leg in a combat. The greatest punishment for criminals is to break their horns.

The different type and forms of horns impacts the individual's attractiveness to mates. The race utilizes them for courtship and **I like the idea that they allow the species to sense beyond normal human senses.**

Some examples that a human couldn’t feel but that they could would be:

- "The ground and trees are vibrating, a monster is coming from forest, and it's big!"
- "I feel magic on this room, be careful and don’t touch anything"
- On a beautiful sunny day: "We should move fast, a storm is coming"
- "Hold on! An earthquake is coming" - said 3 seconds before the ground
  begins to shake

I want to explain these functions scientifically how could horns allow for the above abilities to exist.

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you could limit potential answers a bit. Some people spend a lot of time writing an answer and if it isn't the direction you want to go in, well, that's sad for the people. For example "they are antenna to receive signals from alien weather broadcasts" might not be what you want (even if it is allowed), but currently it is a viable answer as far as I can see.

Comment: I think i undestand what you mean. Do you need i explain more about world?

Comment: If this is a medieval setting do you really need some in deep explanation? 

Even the great sages of the time will probably just shrug and say "Well, their horns do this and that, its probably because of humors."

Comment: Welcome to the site Zarkyon.  I made some edits to your post for read-ability as well as to keep you from running afoul of some site rules.  Questions on the site should be specific and brainstorming is not the purpose of the site (though we do that in [chat] )

Comment: Also check out the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea of how the site works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horned Humanoids?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103081/horned-humanoids)

Comment: @Sasha I think an answer involving such argumentation, considering the world view of those times and all of that, would be excellent and I might learn something. Now I really want to know. I hope you have the time to write that one

Comment: @Will, it down't look like a duplicate to me.  It isn't asking how they developed the horns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Infrasonic hearing

Regarding earthquakes and large beasts, and possibly storms as well, a reasonable detection method would be [infrasonic hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound); that is a hearing organ designed to detect vibration below the standard threshold of the human ear. There are some experiments suggesting that humans get weird 'feelings' from vibrations as low as 17 Hz, even though they cannot hear them. Whales can detect noises down to 7 Hz.

To detect true [seismic noises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_noise#Characterization_of_the_vibration_properties_of_civil_engineering_structures), a hearing range more like 1 Hz would be reasonable. These vibrations can propagate long distances, allowing the hear-er to detect things from far off.

I won't speculate on possible ways that the horn could act as a 'seismograph' of sorts, since there are many and that would be good for a follow up question. But two things come to mind. First, any horn capable of detecting such vibrations would not be appropriate for use in combat or anything like that. Second, it would be much more effective stuck into the ground or water, since higher density mediums will transmit vibrations better than air. Having the horns on the top of the head is then one of the worst places to have such a detector. Having one on the tip of your tail would be much better.

Comment: This is the answer I would go with, but specify that the horn is not the sensing organ but a protective structure for an organ evolved for detecting [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency). In which case magic produces ELF as well. ELF is produced naturally by earthquakes, lightning, and large animals.

Comment: I like it Kingledion, it's a good argument that explain how works.
@rek Good idea, magic can produce ELF so it's possible to justify that they can sense magic.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of the times the explanation could be:

The horns are composed of a variation of alicornium; the magical substance of the horns are capable of circulating the melancholic humors, usually associated with the more earthen elements. This fabulous material seems to give them a certain measure of precognition on the matters of the natural world, being able to sense the coming of natural disasters.

Most modern doctors offer powdered horn to threat all kinds of mania.

Comment: This is an interesting concept. Creating a new natural material that related to magic maybe can work too.